# Facebook application data storage

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I created a Facebook app(game) in JavaScript. I used Facebook's php-sdk. I dint make a good use of the sdk except to display the name of the user logged, and his details.

I want to store the score of each user at some place. Checked FQL. As far as I saw, it doesnt allow you to store data, there was only SELECT query available. So is there any way in which we can append the score to user information or something similar.

In short can we store the data on Facebook

OR

We should use our own database server only to store the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you need to store your own data. While it might be possible to fake it by using some attribute of a user, it's certainly not the way it's designed to work and you can't count on the data always being available. You are better off setting up your own database and use the users' FB IDs to tie the info together.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook now supports posting scores via scores api found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/).

You can also publish achievements relevant to the game as in [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/)

These have enough guidance to help you out !